# how to exclude a jar file which is packed as a uber jar of an application

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml, maven-plugin

There is an application running with classpath with wildcard *

> e.g java -cp /opt/sampleapp/lib/* Main

which has older version of joda-time(1.8.) which is not having the method DateTime.now() and available from 2.x versions of joda-time.
**Note:**

> This joda time(1.8) is packed in to another jar (jruby-jar-1.6.8.jar
>   file)

I am writing an test application which is using joda-time(above 2.x) version which is having DateTime.now() method & used by my java class. I have to submit my application(jar) file to the running sampleapp to run it. Unfortunately older version is getting picked by during the execution of my test application which is causing

> Caused by: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.joda.time.DateTime.now()Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;`

If i remove the older version of jruby(1.6.8.jar) and replace it with jruby(1.7.18) there is no such error. I am using maven as a build tool & used maven shaded plugin to create a uber jar. How to mention in my application to not to pick the joda-time(1.8) inside the jruby-1.6.8.jar & pick the correct version of joda-time-2.x jar file in my test application.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult.

Your jruby JAR breaks the rules by including the classes of joda time. I can think of different approaches, which all have their disadvantages:

1. Go with the newer version of jruby that does not have the problem.
2. Take the old jruby version and manipulate it: Download it, remove the joda-time classes and upload load it to your maven repository with a version like `1.6.8-fixed`.
3. Shade the other version of joda time for your test application.

Comment: Thanks @JF Meier. I have verified the option 1 and it works fine. But i can't as it is from proprietary which violates the license. For option 2, also not possible because as mentioned above(option 1). For third, not sure about that, but just now i found that jar is transitive dependency of my test app jar. Let me check that.

Comment: is that possible with shade plugin because sampleapp is an separate application which is running and i am creating a jar with maven-jar-plugin to create jars.? any links/references will be really helpful.